# Only display array values that don't contain

Tags: php, regex, arrays

```
foreach ($prefs as $who => $pref) {
 if($who != 'public'){
  $team_users .=$who.',';
  }
 }       
echo $team_users;
```

I'd like to only display data from the array that does not contain the text 'public' in some cases it could be publicXX or public1234, etc.

Comment: `strpos`, `array_filter`, `implode` can all help you.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Even Regex could help him.

Comment: Show us an error or even what you have tried so far and we will gladly help but from how your question is written it only seems like you want us to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/strpos

```
if (strpos($who, 'public') === false) {
  //some code
} else {
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback to achieve this:

```
$result = array_filter($prefs, function($item) {
    return (strpos($item, 'public') === FALSE);
});
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `I'd like to only display data from the array that does not contain the text 'public' in some cases it could be publicXX or public1234, etc.`

Change:

```
if($who != 'public'){...}
```

to this:

```
if(strpos($who, 'public') !== false){...}
```

Comment: I like it but it shows public* entries only, I'm trying to omit public* entires.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($prefs as $who => $pref) {
    if(strpos($who, 'public') !== false){
        $team_users .=$who.',';
    }
}       
echo $team_users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach ($prefs as $who => $pref) {
   if(!preg_match("/public/i", $who)){
       $team_users .= $who.',';
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit overkill compared to `stripos`...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = array('public1', 'asdqwe', 'as33publics', 'helloworld');

$text = implode(', ', array_filter($a, function($v) {
    return strstr($v, 'public') === false;
}));

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with regex.

```
$pattern = '/public/'; 

if(preg_match($pattern,$who)){
//skip to the next entry
}
```

Comment: This also is the opposite of the results I want.  I want to omit public*, this uses public* only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said you want data that does not contain "public" - this finds that data and skips over it (i.e ignores it)